# Как преобразовать массив из int в char*?

Tags: массивы, c++

Имеется int[] массив, содержащий числовые значения. Необходимо каким-либо образом преобразовать его в символьный массив char[] методами с++.

Comment: 1) Если речь идёт о C++, почему `int[]`, а не `std::vector<int>`?  
2) Какой символ, по-вашему, должен получиться из числа 42?

Comment: 1) массив int[], потому что STL еще не освоена =)
2) математический символ, вроде "-"

массив вида: 
int[5] = {5,'+',2,'=',7};

Comment: @Алексей Ливадный:  
1) Поскорей осваивайте STL  
2) А для числа 2147483647 что должно выйти?

Comment: @Алексей Ливадный, а в чём смысл такого преобразования? С массивом интов можно точно так же работать (во всех смыслах, от мат. операций до вывода на экран) как и с массивом char.

Comment: смысл примитивно прост: генерируется мат. выражение, затем один (или несколько) символов (чисел/значений) закрывается символом "?" и выводится на экран, а любознательный пользователь его отгадывает

Comment: Для этого не нужно никаких преобразований вообще, всё это прекрасно делается и с int.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по комменту, надо что-то вроде:

```
int int_data[] = { 5, '+', 2, '=', 7 };
char char_data[sizeof(int_data)/sizeof(int_data[0])];

for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(int_data)/sizeof(int_data[0]); i++ )
{
    int c = int_data[i];
    if( c >= 0 && c <= 9 )
    {
        char_data[i] = c + '0';
    }
    else if( strchr( "+-=/*%", c ) )
    {
        char_data[i] = c;
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Фигня какая-то: %d\n", c );
        break;
    }
}
```

Но к C++ всё это не имеет никакого отношения.